# Is it possible to disable/enable a jquery function on change of radio button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, codeigniter

I am working on the checkout part of an online store. I created a script to be triggered once a form was submitted. i want this script to activate only if the selected payment method is not `paypal` since i want to skip the ajax process.

I am using codeigniter framework

Here's the code for the view

```
<form  action="<?php echo site_url('products/order')?>" method="post" id="checkoutForm" name="checkoutForm">
   ...
   <input type="radio" name="paymentMethod" value="cod">CASH ON DELIVERY
   <input type="radio" name="paymentMethod" value="paypal">PAYPAL
   ...
   <input type="submit" id="btnOrder" value="ORDER NOW">
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var paymentMethod = '';
  $(document).ready(function(){
      $('input:radio[name="paymentMethod"]').change(function(){
           paymentMethod = $(this).val();

      });

   if(paymentMethod != 'paypal' && paymentMethod != ''){
      $('#checkoutForm').submit(function(){
         ...
         $.post($('#checkoutForm').attr('action'), $('#checkoutForm').serialize(), function( data ) {
           ...  
         }, 'json');
      return false;     
      });
    }
  });
</script>
```

Here's the code for the function in my controller (products.php)

```
public function order() {
    $paymentMethod = $this->input->post('paymentMethod');
    ...
    if($paymentMethod != 'paypal'){
        echo json_encode(array('stat' => 1,'msg' => 'Registered Successfully', 'order_id' => $order_id));

     }else{
        // ... Some paypal configurations
        $this->paypal->pay(); //Proccess the payment
    }


} # End order
```

What i've tried so far was to put an if statement outside the `$('#checkoutForm').submit` to check if radio button value is not paypal, but it's not working.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Try `paymentMethod !== 'paypal'`, as `!=` is not checking as strict as `!=` is

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to get the value, and do the checks, when the form is submitted. Right now you're doing the checks when the page first loads, before the value is even changed.

```
$('#checkoutForm').submit(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();

     var paymentMethod = $('input:radio[name="paymentMethod"]').val();

     if(paymentMethod != 'paypal' && paymentMethod != ''){

         $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize(), function( data ) {
           ...  
         }, 'json');
     }
});
```